# Event executes functions couple times in recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, event-handling

I have similar problem in my main project. Down below I shown my problem to the simplified way. I know why my code in executing couple times, the question is how to repair this.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var number = 1;

function load() {
    console.log(number);
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => add(e))
};

function add(e) {
    number += 1;
    load();
    e.stopPropation();
}

load();
```

And of course when I click the button first time everything is fine, but when I click second time, the button executes function two times, after third click four times and so on. I thought that `e.stopPropation();` will solve the problem, but unfortunately is not.

Main Question:
How to kill events which are doubled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here use this

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var number = 1;

function load() {
  console.log(number);
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => add(e));
}

function add(e) {
  number += 1;
  load();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

load();
```

Comment: Thanks Man! That helped, in my main project also :)